# Integration with fourth power in the denominator

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

$$ \int _\infty ^\infty\int _\infty ^\infty \frac {(z_1 -z_2)^2}{(k+(z_1 -z_2)^2)^2} \exp(-z_1^2 -z_2^2)dz_1 dz_2$$

I have been tried substituting $z_1-z_2$ by y, then using some substitution like $x=\frac {\exp(-y)^2}{(1+y^2)}$, but things have not worked out. Is there a better way?

Comment: I do not think this particular substitution works, since $y^2=(z_{1}-z_{2})^2=z_{1}^2-2z_{1}z_{2}+z_{2}^2\neq-z_{1}^2-z_{2}^2$, which would be in the exponential.

Comment: Yes, I mention that in my question, as something that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By letting $\frac{z_1+z_2}{\sqrt{2}}=u, \frac{z_1-z_2}{\sqrt{2}}=v$ the given integral takes the form
$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{2v^2}{(k+2v^2)^2}e^{-u^2-v^2}\,du\,dv =\sqrt{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4v}{(k+2v^2)^2}\cdot ve^{-v^2}dv$$
and by integration by parts the RHS equals
$$ \sqrt{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-2v^2}{k+2v^2}e^{-v^2}\,dv =\frac{\pi}{2k}-\sqrt{\pi}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2v^2}{k+2v^2}e^{-v^2}\,dv$$
where the last term is non-elementary (it depends on the error function), but by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2v^2}{k+2v^2}e^{-v^2}\,dv\leq\sqrt{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2v}{k+2v^2}\right)^2\,dv\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(ve^{-v^2}\right)^2\,dv}=\frac{\pi^{3/4}}{2^{5/2}k^{1/4}}.$$

Comment: This looks great, really like the trick in the first substitution. I was wondering why you did not just rewrite $1-2v^2$ as $(k+1)-(k+2v^2)$. The first part would integrate easily, and the second part *might* work too.

Comment: @Juanito: of course, the original question turns out to be equivalent to the computation of $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-v^2}\,dv}{k+2v^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I also ask you how you replaced  $dz_1 dz_2$ with $du dv$ with the substitution? Direct substitution of values does not lead to it.

Comment: @Juanito: it is a standard change of variable in a double integral (so you have to compute a Jacobian). It is just a $45^\circ$ rotation of the plane (hence the determinant of the Jacobian is one, since rotations are isometries).